# Removing usage of Arb.registerByType from Xunit test using FsCheck

Tags: f#, xunit, fscheck

I am testing a round-trip of a `Thoth.Json` Encoder / Decoder pair.

It looks like this:

```ml
type CustomArbitrary =
  static member String() =
    Arb.Default.String()
    |> Arb.filter (not << isNull)

[<Fact>]
let ``Encode.foo Decode.foo round-trip`` () =
  let roundTrip (x : Foo) =
    let json =
      x
      |> Encode.foo
      |> Encode.toString 2

    let decoded =
      json
      |> Decode.fromString Decode.foo

    Ok x = decoded

  // Necessary?
  Arb.registerByType (typeof<CustomArbitrary>) |> ignore

  Check.QuickThrowOnFailure (roundTrip)
```

The test fails if I do not filter out `null` values for `System.String`. However, `null` is not a proper value inside `Foo` so that is fine.

However, I don't like the usage of `Arb.registerByType` here due to global state etc.

How can I rewrite this test so that `Arb.registerByType` is not necessary?

Ideally, I would design a FsCheck config once and pass that to each test.

Comment: Writing a Generator I guess.

Comment: @citykid I don't want to write a whole generator for `Foo` because then I need to keep updating it as `Foo` changes... aside from `null` strings, the default generator is good.

Comment: @sdgfsdh: Just curious if you found my suggestions below helpful.

Comment: @brianberns Sorry yes, the vanilla FsCheck is what I went with in the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using vanilla FsCheck

Create the config once like this:

```ml
let config =
    {
        FsCheck.Config.Default with
            Arbitrary = [ typeof<CustomArbitrary> ]
    }
```

Then use it to check each test like this:

```ml
Check.One(config, roundTrip)
```

---

### Using FsCheck.Xunit

If you switch to `Properties`/`Property` instead of `Fact`, you don't even need an explicit `config` instance or the `Check` class:

```ml
open FsCheck.Xunit

[<Properties(Arbitrary=[| typeof<CustomArbitrary> |])>]
module MyTests =

    [<Property>]
    let ``Encode.foo Decode.foo round-trip`` (x : Foo) =
        let json =
          x
          |> Encode.foo
          |> Encode.toString 2

        let decoded =
          json
          |> Decode.fromString Decode.foo

        Ok x = decoded

    [<Property>]
    let ``Some other test`` () =
        true
```

More info on this approach [here](https://fscheck.github.io/FsCheck/RunningTests.html#Using-FsCheck-Xunit).

By the way, be careful about using `.` characters in your test names, because some test frameworks (e.g. Visual Studio) use them to define a test hierarchy.